# Using notify-send with cron

Tags: cron, notify

I've been trying to use `notify-send` with cron. I've checked out tons of answers given on stackoverflow and other forums. But I don't see the notify-send popup appearing. I'm currently running Ubuntu 13.10. I've been able to get this to work earlier (about 3 months ago when I had Ubuntu 11.10) but I don't remember how and I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

My current crontab looks like:

```
*/1 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && export XAUTHORITY=/home/harold/.Xauthority && /usr/bin/notify-send "$(date)"
```

I've tried many solutions given online including using `sudo -u harold` right before `/usr/bin/notify-send ...`. I've also tried using `export DISPLAY=:0` instead of `=:0.0`. The popup still doesn't appear.

I've also tried to create a script. The cron job to run the script looks like:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/harold/bin && ./notify-send-test.sh
```

And my script (`notify-send-test.sh`) looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#export DISPLAY=:0
#export XAUTHORITY=/home/harold/.Xauthority
/usr/bin/notify-send "$(date)"
echo "trying to notify at $(date)" >> /home/harold/bin/cronlog.txt
```

I've tried using the commented lines and not using them. None of the combinations seem to work. I've also tried using `export DISPLAY=0.0`.

I do get the expected output in the cronlog.txt file every minute. This means that my script is being executed but the notify-send is not.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Happy to provide any more information that may be of use.

Secondary question:
There was also something about cron not being able to use certain environment variables. I don't get what that meant and how it affects the way I use cron. It would be nice if someone could explain this.

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: @fraxture, I had to give up working on this for a while (quite a long while). I am hoping to to try and give it another go sometime though I don't know when yet.

Answer (score 7):

To add to Sakthi's answer.

You can get the **DBUS_SESSIONBUS_ADDRESS** withouth using nautilus (or gnome or whatever) by typing `dbus-launch` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41244272/8869645))

So to the script would simply be:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export $(dbus-launch)
/usr/bin/notify-send "$(date)"
```

If that doesn't work, you could try setting it hard-coded to your user ID:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
userid=$(id -u)
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/$userid/bus"
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
/usr/bin/notify-send "$(date)"
```

You can add `echo $(env | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS)` in the script to check what the env variable is when the script is executed.

Comment: Thats brilliant it was the only code that works for me, I need this for network usage monitoring it works very well ...

Answer (score 4):

The **DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS** env variable will not be set in cron daemon. Setting this value will fix your issue. Add the following changes to your .sh file and call it from crontab.

***notify-send-test.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash
username=$(/usr/bin/whoami)
pid=$(pgrep -u $username nautilus)
dbus=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$pid/environ | sed 's/DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=//' )
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$dbus
/usr/bin/notify-send "$(date)"
```

***Crontab***

*/1 * * * * /home/harold/bin/notify-send-test.sh

Comment: and without nautilus?