# How to export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

Tags: linux, dbus, yocto

I'm trying to run D-Bus on an embedded system (Yocto Linux) and connect to it from my application code.

I get the following error when I call `dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &err);`

```
Using X11 for dbus-daemon autolaunch was disabled 
at compile time, set your DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS 
instead
```

I realize that I need to start the `dbus-daemon` first so I have run `dbus-launch` from the command line.

This prints out a value of `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` but how could I export it programmatically?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've finally found the answer, running the following command exports the output of dbus-launch:

```
export $(dbus-launch)
```

Comment: This starts a new `dbus-daemon` process. Is that desirable?

Comment: I probably is in a "embedded" system, where you have to explicitly start everything in order to preserve resources.

Comment: This seems to be X11 specific, does not work on Wayland.

Answer (score 9):

```
pid_gnome=$(pgrep gnome-session)
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/${pid_gnome}/environ|cut -d= -f2-)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=${DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS}
```

Please make sure that the user has the DISPLAY variable set.

Another alternative is:

```
export $(dbus-launch)
```

Comment: `pgrep gnome-session` may output multiple PIDs (e.g. three processes on Ubuntu 20.04), so it should be `pgrep gnome-session | head -1`. `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep ... | cut -d= -f2-)` ends with `000a` (`\0\n`), which causes warning `bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input` when `export`. So it should be `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep ... | cut -d= -f2- | tr -d '\0\n')`.

Comment: WIth `grep -P`, `| cut` is not needed.
`export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -P -o -a "(?<=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=).+?(?=\x00)" /proc/"$(pgrep gnome-session | head -1)"/environ)`

Answer (score 8):

Type the following command into a terminal:

```
eval `dbus-launch --auto-syntax`
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Please fix your backslash. I cannot because it would not be enough characters to allow a change.

Comment: This is not good ans. After doing this, I cant use RDP.

Answer (score 2):

When you launch your user session, do it like this:

```
dbus-daemon --session --fork --print-address 1 > /tmp/dbus-session-addr.txt
```

This will cause the session address to be written to `/tmp/dbus-session-addr.txt`. (The filename's not that important, it's just somewhere you've decided to store it.)

Then, when you need the variable set:

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(cat /tmp/dbus-session-addr.txt)
```

If your shell's sniffy about export-during-definition - some can be - do it in two stages:

```
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(cat /tmp/dbus-session-addr.txt)
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to get the value of DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in order for your application to run correctly.  Try running it with dbus-run-session instead of dbus-launch.  According to https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-launch.1.html
dbus-launch should not be run from the command line, but in a shell script
(see also https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-run-session.1.html).

Answer (score -7):

Type in terminal:

```
export $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

Comment: If the variable is not set, exporting it will not solve anything, thus $(dbus-launch) solves this issue.

Comment: This is worse than wrong as it will try to export a variable named after the contents of DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS which makes no sense.