# Git + libsecret throws "Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY"

Tags: git, unix, centos, x11, dbus

I've installed Git and libsecret on an CentOS 7 Server. I used git-credentials-store to store my credentials in clear text on the server. Now I wanna use libsecret but unfortunately I'm getting D-Bus errors, if I configure git-credential-libsecret as credential helper.

I've already installed dbus and dbus-x11 and launched dbus via below command but I'm still getting errors.

> dbus-launch --sh-syntax

Error:

> $ git pull origin master
>
> ** (process:66155): CRITICAL **: 08:19:33.936: could not connect to Secret Service: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
>
> ** (process:66160): CRITICAL **: 08:19:34.209: store failed: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

**EDIT:**

After installation of gnome-keyring I get the following error

> ** Message: 14:10:49.566: Remote error from secret service: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection' on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `export $(dbus-launch)` to evaluate the variables which `dbus-launch` outputs, so that `${DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS}` is set in your environment. See also: [How to export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242460/how-to-export-dbus-session-bus-address)

If `${DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS}` is not set in your environment, the D-Bus client library will assume no `dbus-daemon` is running and will attempt to auto-launch one. Without a `${DISPLAY}`, that’s not possible; hence the error message you see.

Comment: Thanks @Philip! Now I'm getting the following errors ** (process:46160): CRITICAL **: lookup failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files

Comment: Make sure that the file `org.freedesktop.secrets.service` is installed into the directory where your session bus is configured to look for services. Typically this is `/usr/share/dbus-1/services`, but might be different if you’re using a custom configuration.

I suspect you’ve installed libsecret in a custom prefix rather than system-wide, which would cause this problem. Did you use the distro-provided RPMs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I didn't find that file on the filesystem. I've installed libsecret via the provided yum repos.

Comment: It might be provided by the `gnome-keyring` package instead of libsecret. It certainly is on Fedora.

Comment: If someone wants to launch dbus with fixed address, set an environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` with the value `unix:path=some_directory` and enter the command `dbus-daemon --session --fork --address=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > somefile`. In my case I couldn't use `export $(dbus-launch)` cause its value changes every time I launch it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it headless, but you need to follow the recommendations from the Python keyring package to "trick" it.

https://keyring.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-keyring-on-headless-linux-systems