# Storing git credentials using libsecret: org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection interface not found

Tags: git, credentials

I'm trying to store my git credentials using libsecret on Ubuntu 20.04. I followed these instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev gnome-keyring
sudo make --directory=/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
    
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

I also export the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`: `export $(dbus-launch)`.

However, after logging in, I get the following error when libsecret tries to store the credentials. It seems a class is missing somewhere, but I haven't found an answer where to get it.

```
store failed: No such interface ?org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection? on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login
```

Does anybody know what am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53630430/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67115243/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=store+failed%3A+No+such+interface+org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection+on+object+at+path+%2Forg%2Ffreedesktop%2Fsecrets%2Fcollection%2Flogin

Answer (score 0):

I got the **same error message** when I try to connect with vpn client tool. I solved my problem with installing "gnome-keyring" package.

```
yum install gnome-keyring
```